# How to committed JPA entity in another transaction

Tags: jpa, ejb

I have a follow entity:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String state;

    @Version
    private Long version;
    ... getter and setter
}
```

and multi EJBs for impl business:

```
@Stateless
public class EntityDao{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="")
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createEntity1(Entity1 e)
    {
        e.status = "start";
        em.persist(e);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void changeToTimeout(Entity1 e)
    {
        e.status = "timeout";
        em.merge(e);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyService
{

    @EJB
    EntityDao dao;

    @EJB
    MyService2 ms2;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void doWork()
    {
       Entity1 e = new Entity1();
       dao.createEntity1(e);
       e = em.find(Entity1.class, e.getId());
       em.refresh(e);
       ms2.handle(e);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyService2
{
    @EJB
    EntityDao dao;

    public void handle(Entity1 e)
    {
       e.name = "M";
       dao.changeToTimeout(e);
... and other statement that effected on e object
    }
 }
```

in this state if before calling dao.changeToTimeout(), object version changed and increased, I get OptimisticException, if in changeToTimeout() first finded object and then changed status field, changes in another transaction ignored because this transaction don't know another transaction JPA context.

Is there a way for join two JPA context?

Comment: Have you tried doing an `em.refresh(e)` in your `changeToTimeout` method? Before you change the status.

Comment: I set entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

Comment: then because the default value of synchronization is SynchronizationType.SYNCHRONIZED, I sent entitymanager to new transaction and merged my entity to it. After second transaction commited, in first transaction merged the entity and detached it and merged it again. With this work JPA ignored to flush entity changing.

Answer (score 0):

Change transaction attribute type to required.

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

It will join the client transaction context.

Right now you have '`REQUIRES_NEW`', means always start with a new transaction context.

Comment: I need new transaction which if first transaction rollback,the entity state changed to timeout.